# Safari 6.1 won't play audio from embedded Soundcloud widget

Tags: audio, safari, soundcloud

I have embedded the Soundcloud widget on my website here:
http://www.jackcarnoldmusic.co.uk/music/

…however, on Safari 6.1 (the latest version), no audio plays.  There is no error returned, and the time counter and play cursor move, but no sound comes out.  Same page loaded in other browsers, including IOS7, work fine.  What is it that Safari 6.1 is doing to stop the audio, and how do I get around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I solved this same problem as follows:

Safari - Preferences - Advanced - **unchecked** Internet plug-ins (Stop plug-ins to save power)

Reloaded my page with embedded Soundcloud widget & I now get the audio to stream.

This new Safari feature causes other plug-ins to have a similar problem. Not sure what Apple is thinking sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of Safari Power Saver. SoundCloud uses Flash to play audio, but puts it somewhere it in the page making Safari think it's not an important Flash instance (it's not front and center) so it must be blocked to save power. Unfortunately SoundCloud also visually hides Flash, making it impossible to click on it, therefore making it impossible for Safari to put it in the Power Saver whitelist. Also unfortunately, there is no way to add more websites to that list from Safari.

Fortunately though, it was easy enough to create a tool that fixes that. So here is [Safari Power Saver Whitelister](https://gist.github.com/crmne/5855a901a0a9a6ef30a5). It adds any website you want to the Safari Power Saver whitelist. Just click Run in the AppleScript Editor.