# Safari won't play audio for Soundcloud widget, but for only 1 of the 3 files

Tags: audio, safari, soundcloud

Link in question: https://www.presskit.to/pirramusic

If you play the featured song, 'Paradise' on the top of the main section in Safari, it will start playing, but no audio. Everything else seems to work fine, just no sound is heard (did all the troubleshooting to confirm that this is the case, so mute, volume, etc was checked)

Now, here's the strange part. Click on `Media` you'll see the same file embedded with the other songs. If you click play on THAT song, it WILL play the audio normally.

So I googled around, found this stackoverflow question that's semi related: [Safari 6.1 won't play audio from embedded Soundcloud widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593329/safari-6-1-wont-play-audio-from-embedded-soundcloud-widget)

(and this: http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1464535-why-can-t-i-hear-tracks-using-safari-)

So I uncheck that box and it works, but that doesn't really fix the two issues i have:

1. I can't do that automatically for my users. Nor is okay to give them
   instructions on how to do this, since they shouldn't ever ever have
   to mess with browser settings to make my site work.
2. Why is the issue only with the top embed/iframe? If it's 'saving power' or whatever,
   it makes sense that 2 out of the 3 work.

Some other notes:

- I'm running Safari Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9)
- On a 2013 MBA 13" running mavericks
- Works fine in other browsers
- The embed code for the two players (the one that works and the one
  that doesnt) is identical. See page source.

Other question:

- Would having the same objected embedded twice cause an issue? If it
  did, i figure it would be with SoundCloud's side and would be
  affecting all browsers.

Please help, im pretty stumped on this. If it's a bug, i'll report it to apple, but i'm not sure if it is yet. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, Soundcloud provided a page with an explanation on how to make it work. It is however bad UX, as - as you stated - there doesn't seem to be a way to make it work automatically for users.

here is the link to soundclods answer: http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1464535-why-can-t-i-hear-tracks-using-safari-

HOWEVER, we do need to have the player working :) so if somebody knows a way, please share.